# "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when reading environment variable from mongoDB

Tags: html, angular, mongodb

I am trying to read a variable which is defined in my javascript. It is a get request from a mongoDB. The whole database is then stored under a variable and is read by the HTML and displayed.

The get request from the MongoDB has an output like this:
(Lets say this is stored under the variable `database`):

```
[
  {
      0:
           {
                TITLE1: valueone
           }
  },
  {
      1:
           {
                TITLE2: valuetwo
           }
  }
]
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<p> {{ database?.TITLE1 }} </p>
```

I get the error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. I understand this is because I need to define `[0]` to be able to read `TITLE1`.

Based on this I have tried the following:

```
<p> {{ database?[0].TITLE1 }} </p>
```

This has this error: `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Conditional expression database?[0].TITLE1 requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [{{ database?[0].TITLE1 }}]`

```
<p> {{ database?.[0].TITLE1 }} </p>
```

This has this error: `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 7 in [{{ database?.[0].TITLE1 }}]`

```
<p> {{ database?.0.TITLE1 }} </p>
```

This has the same error as the one above.

What is the correct way to be able to read the values that I am after. In the HTML the output should be `valueone`.

Comment: You have the array containing object with key-value pairs each containing another object with keys like `TITLE`, so `database[i][j]['TITLE' + k]` should work

Comment: `I understand this is because I need to define [0] to be able to read TITLE1.`: that's wrong, it means that you are trying to read the property 0, somewhere. Maybe the problem isn't there, but I'm sure you're trying to **read** 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your database is array, use need use `[0]` to get first item and your key is number so you need use `['0']` to get property value, you also can use ? to check object `null` before using `TITLE1`

Finally you can use `{{ database[0]['0']?.TITLE1 }}`

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o79rra

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <p> {{ database[0]['0']?.TITLE1 }} </p>
```

Do it dynamically by:

```
    <p *ngFor="let item of database; let i = index">
       {{item[i]['TITLE' + (i + 1)]}}
    </p>
```

Comment: I get the error: `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 10 in [{{database?[0].[0].TITLE1}}]`

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. Edited the answer

Comment: @Dritz I have updated the answer to do it dynamically. Tested it. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Well I mean, at some point you have to think a little about JS basics instead of trying everything until it works ...

**From the code you have provided**, the syntax would be

```
{{ data[0]['0'].TITLE1 }}
```

Comment: When using this I get the error: `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 10 in [{{ data[0].['0'].TITLE1 }}]`. When is js to get the data I am after I would use `database[0].TITLE1`. I based my attempts for the HTML off of this.

Comment: @Dritz Woops my bad, big fingers, `{{ data[0]['0'].TITLE1 }}` without the `.` between the two zeros

Comment: Unfortunately even without the `.` I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Dritz then provide a [mcve] because [it clearly works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzpcea)